# How can i get the chat admin user using telethon

Tags: chat, channel, telethon

Am trying to get the admin user of a chat using the following.

```
 client.iter_participants(channel, filter=ChannelParticipantsAdmins)
```

But using this I can only get the admin user of the channel, but not the admin user of the chat.

Comment: Am not quite getting what the difference is. The method above gets you all admins if they are more than one.

Comment: If the group calls this, it will return all members, not just the administrator.@Caleb Njiiri